# How can I import tensorflow model from CNTK?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, cntk

I want to deploy my tensorflow model in C++ application that uses CNTK.
How can I import tensorflow model from CNTK?

Is there any utility tool from transforming learned models into from digestable for CNTK?
What solution would you suggest here?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way I can think of is to save all your weights into files and re-create the network structure in CNTK. It is probably easier to do in Python. Once you do that you can save the model and load it in C++.

An example of how to do this is in [this notebook](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/nikosk/neuralstyle/Tutorials/CNTK_205_Artistic_Style_Transfer.ipynb) which will soon be on the CNTK master branch (when it is in master the above url will stop working and the correct url will be [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_205_Artistic_Style_Transfer.ipynb).